# How to set variable properties use less duplicate code in C++?

Tags: c++, copy, metaprogramming

How to reduce code duplication in variable properties setting?

```
struct test1
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int f;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct test2
{
    int a;
    int b;
    // int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

int main(){
    test1 t1;
    test2 t2{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    // set attributes
    t1.a = t2.a;
    t1.b = t2.b;
    t1.c = 0;
    t1.d = t2.d;
    t1.f = 11;
    t1.x = t2.x;
    t1.y = t2.y;
    t1.z = t2.z;
}
```

code like above, there are 2 structs :test1、test2 and their objects t1 and t2,their attributes are mostly the same, I want use t2' to set t1's attributes,of course I can do it like above,but I think there could be ways to set their attributes easier and faster(maybe in the future,there attributes nums couble be 100 or more)

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` or something similar.

Comment: If test data is related make a base structure and derive test1/test2 from that (or give test1 a copy constructors/assignment operator that allows you to assign from test1). otherwise keep it as it is. Developing code is usually NOT about finding the least amount of code to do things.

Comment: No, the attributes shouldn't be "100 or more". Instead, what should be would be an array, or soe other suitabel container.

Comment: Maybe you can explain WHY you think you need so many test parameters? And WHAT you want to do?

Comment: In practice, you really don't want that. In Cobol we have a MOVE CORRESPONDING that copies members with the same name. All coding guidelines say that you should never use that, because as soon as you change anything in one struct, it no longer does the right thing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer here is WHAT i want to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76361291/how-to-set-two-similar-msgs-attributes-with-less-duplicate-codes-in-c

Comment: There is an answer there already, you can nest your messages. E.g. make common parts seperate messages in your proto file.And then in  C++ you will have seperate generated classes as well. In the end however you will still need to set the properties. And yes sometimes coding is like this, tedious and explicit.